# Word "Hello" assignment to array of chr's in C

Tags: c, arrays

In C that's legal and will compile:

```
char names[5] = "Hello";
```

but this one is not:

```
char names[5];

names = "Hello";
```

How do I put assignment in array of characters word "Hello" ? Can I do that without `strcpy` ?

Comment: your names string should be at least of 6 chars, 5 + 1(for '\0')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. In C **an array is not an lvalue** so you can't assign to it.

The only ways to do it:

- Use a copying function (like `memcpy` or `strcpy` for example)
- Assign all the elements one at a time (*eew*)
- Use a pointer instead of an array. There is some folk knowledge that "an array is just a pointer". **[It's](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) [not](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) [true](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html)** (yes, those are 3 links).

Comment: Thanks. I will try something else then.

Answer (score 1):

Your `names` string should have at least 6 (not 5) characters, because of the terminating null byte:

```
char names[6];
```

Either with `strcpy` or with the equivalent code, e.g.

```
names[0] = 'H';
names[1] = 'e';
names[2] = 'l';
names[3] = 'l';
names[4] = 'o';
names[5] = (char)0;
```

And a recent version of `gcc` (i.e. 4.6), when asked for enough optimization (`-O2`), would optimize `strcpy(names,"Hello");` into equivalent of above code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going to have problems. C strings have an extra null character at the end. "Hello" requires 6 bytes. I believe your string "Hello" is going to turn into "Hell" in the first example.

Comment: enumeration starts from 0 so there is actually 6 places for chars.

Comment: @Edgar no, you reserved 5 characters and that is what you get, there is no extra char magically added so indeed with your char names[5] = "Hello"; you are overwriting memory, better to write char names[] =...